# onClickListener from AdapterMain

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I try create a onClickListener from my AdapterMain but when i click on the recycleView item it crashes

```
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterMain.myviewholder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position, @NonNull final model model) {
    holder.name.setText(model.getName());
    holder.course.setText(model.getCourse());
    holder.email.setText(model.getEmail());
    Glide.with(holder.img.getContext()).load(model.getPurl()).into(holder.img);
    
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailTruyen.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

logcat:
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.apptruyen, PID: 4452
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ComponentName.(ComponentName.java:131)
at android.content.Intent.(Intent.java:6858)
at com.example.apptruyen.adapter.AdapterMain$1.onClick(AdapterMain.java:46)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Is there a way to add the onClickListener to my MainActivity

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: There are *a lot* of existing questions and other resources about this error. I recommend checking those out: https://www.google.com/search?q=Android+Adapter+Attempt+to+invoke+virtual+method+%27java.lang.String+android.content.Context.getPackageName%28%29%27+on+a+null+object+reference+at+android.content.ComponentName.%28ComponentName.java%3A131%29+at+android.content.Intent.%28Intent.java%3A6858%29+at